# What is y_pred in keras?

Tags: python, keras

In the keras-ocr example, they are using CTC loss function. In the model compile line,

```
# the loss calc occurs elsewhere, so use a dummy lambda function for the loss
model.compile(loss={'ctc': lambda y_true, y_pred: y_pred}, optimizer=sgd)
```

they are using a dummy lambda function with y_true,y_pred as inputs and y_pred as output. But y_pred was already defined previously as the softmax activation.

```
y_pred = Activation('softmax', name='softmax')(inner)
```

If y_pred is softmax activation then where is CTC loss being used?. Does y_pred mean the output of the last previous layer, in keras irrespective of whether it has already been defined?. (because in the code, the layer's output just before the compile line is CTC loss).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it is said in the comment, the loss calculation is already done somewhere else, so the `{'ctc': lambda y_true, y_pred: y_pred}` just takes already pre-calculated loss in `y_pred` and discards `y_true` as not needed without any calculations.

Comment: "just takes already pre-calculated loss in y_pred". There is no line in the code which does that. The loss is precalculated, yes, but I can't see where it's assigned to the y_pred variable.

Comment: @timedacorn the actual loss is calculated by `ctc_lambda_func()` (line 334), which is used in building the `loss_out` layer, inside the model (lines 475 and 480).

Comment: so the loss_out layer's output is the `y_pred` value which is being passed to the model.compile right?

Comment: @timedacorn nope. the `loss_out` layer computes the loss. `model.compile()` gets a lambda function, with the arbitrarily named arguments, which can be `a` and `b` or `x` and `y` or `y_pred` and `y_true`. the first argument is discarded, the second is used as the loss. argument names are chosen exclusively for easy understanding =)